# How to change mount options with terminal?

Tags: command-line, automount, system-settings

please correct any mistakes. So I went in to the drive application and disabled the auto mount in mount options. When I rebooted I can only start in the grub mode and can only access safe mode.

Note. I found a command that seems to remount the drive but, then I get login loop.
(Ubuntu17.10)

I'm assuming I just need to figure out how to manually mount my sda

Comment: login loop for terminal? or gui?  Did you mount your /home directory too? *as your gui needs to write files there otherwise you're logged out :)*

Comment: I use sudo mount -rw -o remount /dev/sda1 /       so that I can go to the normal login and their is the loop

Comment: yes I saw that answer which will work *if* you don't have a separate */home* partition; my comment was in case you do have one...

Comment: Since I start In grub mode I hit the "ubuntu" seems to start normally but it then fully loads and there is a black screen with no way to use mouse. There is just an option to login to the command I think is what it is. Thanks

Comment: Black screen with no mouse sounds like graphics issue to me... I would suggest removing `splash quiet` from your boot, maybe adding a '1' (or single to go into single-user or maintenance mode) to undo whatever you did (hopefully its in `history`  if you used terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Boot the computer into recovery mode

Select root in the menu, so you can open the shell.

then run the following command.

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

When you have done this, you can try run the command to fix the issues.

**PS! Remember backups important stuff first ;)**

Comment: If your stuck in a loginloop you can try to do this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: Thanks BD Bear but that didn't do it.

Comment: can you get your hands some logs ? 

tail /var/log/syslog
tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log and put them on pastebin , and put a link in the comment?

Comment: If you cant find the xorg logfile, do a ls /var/log/Xorg* to se if perhaps it has a different number in its name. or check if you can find it in ~/.local/share/xorg/